# Revoked certificate - iPhone Programming

Tags: ios, certificate

I deleted a certificate in Provisioning Portal (Certificates). Now, when I want create a new certificate I see a warning and this message is sent to my email:

> Your Development Certificate Has Been Revoked - you have revoked your
>   Development certificate and it's no longer valid

My account is valid.

What can I do to add new certificate without problems or restore the old one that I have on disk?

Comment: how do you create new certificate?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Manual Way:**

1. Go to this URL (Apple developer site):
   https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action
2. Log in with your valid account.
3. On the right-hand side, there is a column with a heading "iOS Developer Program". Select the "Provisioning Portal" section.
4. On the left-hand side, click the row of the column that is labeled "Certificates"
5. Since I already have a certificate I'm not sure, but somewhere on this page you should be able to click "Request certificate" or something similar.
6. Wait for your new certificate, and then download and install it as before

Other details can be found in Apple's Tech Notes here: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html

**You can ALSO have XCode create everything for you.**

1. Revoke all current certificates and provisioning profiles
2. To invoke "Automatic Device Provisioning" open Xcode's "Window" menu > Organizer > Devices tab > "Provisioning Profile" sidebar under Library.
3. Check the "Automatic Device Provisioning" checkbox and click the "Refresh" button. After clicking Refresh a dialog should appear requesting your team member account credentials. It is important to answer 'yes' when asked to create your iPhone Certificates if any are needed. In that case, clicking "Submit Request" will allow Xcode to create, download and install the certificate(s).

**What XCode is doing for you automatically, according  to the above tech note:**

1) Prompts to create and install your "iPhone Developer" certificate if one doesn't already exist in the iOS Portal

2) (for admin or agent roles) prompts to create and install your "iPhone Distribution" certificate if one doesn't already exist in the iOS Portal

3) Creates a Wildcard App ID if one does not already exist in the iOS Portal

4) Creates, or updates with new devices added to the portal, your iOS Team Provisioning Profile and installs that into your profile library

5) Syncs the profile library on your local machine with the profiles on the iOS Portal

Comment: No problem! I'm glad that I could help!

Comment: With XCode 5, I believe that the steps to have XCode create everything for you are no longer valid.

Comment: @JTApps. my all is live and i accidentally revoked certificate. Will live app will down? what should i do? do i need to create again?

Comment: I needed to restart my device as well

Answer (score 1):

Solution for **Xcode 8**

1. Xcode Preferences > Accounts
2. Choose your account
3. Click 'View Details'
4. Click 'Download all profiles'
5. Restart Xcode
6. This step is optional, meaning that might work without this: Product > press 'alt' button > Clean Build Folder

These solved my issue.