# Your iOS Development certificate has been revoked

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I have submitted my app on the App Store.  It is still waiting for review.
I got mail:

> Your iOS Distribution certificate has been revoked.
>
> Dear Me,
>
> You have revoked your certificate, so it is no longer valid.
>
> Certificate: iOS Development
>
> Team Name: Me
>
> Any provisioning profiles that include this certificate are no longer
>   valid and must be regenerated for future use.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Apple Developer Program Support

I didn't understand what is the reason and what should I do?

Comment: Did you try to generate a new certificate?

Comment: You can create new certificates and add it to your project.

Comment: while submitting build I have generated new certificate @RyanPendleton

Comment: In most cases, generating a new certificate will revoke your old one.

Comment: @RyanPendleton I think I should create new distribution certificate and resubmit app again

Comment: @VinodJadhav Just to clarify, you said you generated a new certificate when submitting the build, right? I'd check to see if you have an active certificate before regenerating another one. Odds are, the email was about an old certificate that you're not using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you delete/ generate new certificate in Provisioning Portal(Certificates) then you get these types of messages "Your Development Certificate Has Been Revoked - you have revoked your Development certificate and it' s no longer valid".

To overcome this you need to generate provisioning profiles with the newly created distribution certificate, sign the build using the same, recreate the build and resubmit the app for review to AppStore.

For more info refer below link-

[Revoked certificate - iPhone Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634321/revoked-certificate-iphone-programming?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

Solution for **Xcode 8**

1. Xcode Preferences > Accounts
2. Choose your account
3. Click 'View Details'
4. Click 'Download all profiles'
5. Restart Xcode
6. This step is optional, meaning that might work without this: Product > press 'alt' button > Clean Build Folder

Had same problem and these steps solved my issue.

Comment: I can't finde 'View Details' after selecting my account.

Comment: @Alfi probaby the answer is not actual because the current Xcode is 11. Sorry