# make revoke certificate to valid in xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am very new in iOS development. I make wrong things for my certificate in xcode and now it become revoke for my account.

My iOS Development is Revoked. and in keychain Access all certificates are gone.
What could I do to be valid again?

Comment: go the developer.apple member centre and create a new one and then install all the pro profiles and certificates again . and import a developer profile to your xcode

Comment: should i need to delete the existing one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in to your Apple developer account and upload a new certificate signing request to get a valid certificate. How to do that check this link: 
https://mobiforge.com/design-development/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices

http://www.aquafadas.com/en/documentation/sample-page/developer-apple-com-2/generating-your-development-certificate/ (Old Link Dead)

Comment: I download the certificate file from my account and I just clicked it. So, at the keychain Access, all certificate's status are green and show valid. But at the xcode's Message, it show "Your account already has been a valid certificate" and it want to revoke and request agian. I think Xcode is not sync with keyChain Acess. Do you have any suggestion?  THanks

Comment: Please delete the older certificate from the keychain and try again. Also in Xcode add your developer account with your developer account credentials.

Comment: Try the new link, I believe the old link is dead now. https://mobiforge.com/design-development/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices

Answer (score 0):

**1st Step (Apple developer site)**

- Go to this URL (Apple developer site):
  [https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action](https://developer.apple.com/download/)
- Log in with your valid account.
- On the right-hand side, there is a column with a heading "iOS
  Developer Program". Select the "Provisioning Portal" section.
- On the left-hand side, click the row of the column that is labeled
  "Certificates"
- Since I already have a certificate I'm not sure, but somewhere on
  this page you should be able to click "Request certificate" or
  something similar.
- Wait for your new certificate, and then download and install it as
  before

**2nd Step (Xcode)**

- Revoke all current certificates and provisioning profiles
- To invoke "Automatic Device Provisioning" open Xcode's "Window" menu

  > Organizer > Devices tab > "Provisioning Profile" sidebar under Library.
- Check the "Automatic Device Provisioning" checkbox and click the
  "Refresh" button. After clicking Refresh a dialog should appear
  requesting your team member account credentials. It is important to
  answer 'yes' when asked to create your iPhone Certificates if any are
  needed. In that case, clicking "Submit

  Request" will allow Xcode to create, download and install the
  certificate(s).

According the 2nd step XCode is doing for you automatically below things

- Prompts to create and install your "iPhone Developer" certificate
  if one doesn't already exist in the iOS Portal
- (for admin or agent roles) prompts to create and install your
  "iPhone Distribution" certificate if one doesn't already exist in the
  iOS Portal
- Creates a Wildcard App ID if one does not already exist in the iOS
  Portal
- Creates, or updates with new devices added to the portal, your iOS
  Team Provisioning Profile and installs that into your profile library
- Syncs the profile library on your local machine with the profiles
  on the iOS Portal

You can also refer apple link [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev3a05256b8)

Comment: You are copying from other Answer. this is not the one that I want.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634321/revoked-certificate-iphone-programming